# Taxonomy Page Go to 404 pgae

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I am creating one custom post type using the Redux Framework. Creating a category and that category view by category directly and directly go to the link but that link should go to directly 404 page. Please check below code and let me know what was an error in my code.

```
remove_action( 'init', 'brightness_service_register',10 );
add_action( 'init', 'brightness_service_register',1 ); 
function brightness_service_register()
{
$labels = array(
'name' => __( 'Service', 'brightness' ),
'add_new' => __( 'Add New', 'brightness' ),
'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Service', 'brightness'),
'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Service', 'brightness'),
'new_item' => __( 'New Service', 'brightness' ),
'view_item' => __( 'View Service', 'brightness' ),
'search_items' => __( 'Search Service', 'brightness' ),
'not_found' => __( 'No items found', 'brightness' ),
'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No items found in Trash', 'brightness' ), 
'parent_item_colon' => '',
'menu_name' => 'Service'
);
$args = array(
'labels' => $labels,
'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-images-alt2',
'public' => true,
'publicly_queryable' => true,
'show_ui' => true,
'show_in_menu' => true,
'query_var' => true,
'capability_type' => 'post',
'has_archive' => true,
'hierarchical' => false,
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'service', 'with_front' => false ),
'exclude_from_search' => true,
'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes'
));
$taxonomy_labels = array(
  'name' => __( 'Service Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
  'singular_name' => __( 'Service Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
  'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Category' ),
  'all_items' => __( 'All Service Categories' ),
  'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Service Category' ),
  'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Location:' ),
  'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Category' ),
  'update_item' => __( 'Update Category' ),
  'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Category' ),
  'new_item_name' => __( 'New Category Name' ),
  'menu_name' => __( 'Service Categories' ),
); 
$taxonomy_args = array(
'hierarchical' => true,
'labels' => $taxonomy_labels,
'rewrite' => array(
  'slug' => 'service-categories', // This controls the base slug that will display before each term
  'with_front' => false, // Don't display the category base before "/locations/"
  'hierarchical' => true // This will allow URL's like "/locations/boston/cambridge/"),); 
register_post_type( 'service' , $args );
register_taxonomy('coll-categories', 'service',$taxonomy_args);
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that when you view these categories, the go to 404 page directly?

Comment: Yes, so please check my code if have any error on it? @AmitJoshi

Answer (score 0):

Basead on wordpress codex,  you need to user `register_taxonomy_for_object_type` to inteconnect the custom post types and custom taxonomies to `be sage than sorry`. So I think adding this after call to `register_taxonomy` line might fix this issue for you.

```
register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'coll-categories', 'service' );
```

Comment: register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'coll-categories', 'service' );

category filed deleted in my custom post type.

Answer (score 0):

well you have done everything right when i pasted your piece of code in array you need to end your array $taxonomy_args

for your answer
You can add `flush_rewrite_rules()` after registering your custom taxonomy.

> NOTE: Flush rules only on activation or deactivation, or when you know that the rewrite rules need to be changed. Don't do it on any hook that will triggered on a routine basis. More detail information in the comments on WP Engineer's post: Custom Post Type and Permalink

**OR**

You can go to **Settings → Permalinks → Save Permalinks**, that should flush the rewrite rules manually.

reference taken from
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/250222/custom-taxonomy-leads-to-404-page

Comment: i have already made it work dude you need to create taxonomy.php to view that

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'init', 'brightness_service_register',0); 
function brightness_service_register()
{

$labels = array(
'name' => __( 'Service', 'brightness' ),
'add_new' => __( 'Add New', 'brightness' ),
'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Service', 'brightness'),

    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Service', 'brightness'),
    'new_item' => __( 'New Service', 'brightness' ),
    'view_item' => __( 'View Service', 'brightness' ),
    'search_items' => __( 'Search Service', 'brightness' ),
    'not_found' => __( 'No items found', 'brightness' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No items found in Trash', 'brightness' ), 
    'parent_item_colon' => '',
    'menu_name' => 'Service'
);
$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-images-alt2',
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'has_archive' => true,
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'service' ),
    'exclude_from_search' => true,
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes'
));
$taxonomy_labels = array(
      'name' => __( 'Service Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
      'singular_name' => __( 'Service Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
      'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Category' ),
      'all_items' => __( 'All Service Categories' ),
      'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Service Category' ),
      'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Location:' ),
      'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Category' ),
      'update_item' => __( 'Update Category' ),
      'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Category' ),
      'new_item_name' => __( 'New Category Name' ),
      'menu_name' => __( 'Service Categories' ),
    ); 
$taxonomy_args = array(
    'labels' => $taxonomy_labels,
    'hierarchical'          => true,
    'show_ui'               => true,
    'show_admin_column'     => true,
    'query_var'             => true,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'service-categories', 'with_front' => false)
);
register_post_type( 'service' , $args );
register_taxonomy('service-categories', 'service',$taxonomy_args);
flush_rewrite_rules();
```

}

Comment: Can you just tell why add taxonomy.php file in my theme?

Comment: taxonomy.php will show all your terms i tested.. it runs nicely all those categories in post types needs to be displayed so taxonomy.php is used

Comment: and I added archive.php code in taxonomy.php file directly go to 404 page but added some print in that file it's working. Please explain it.

Comment: Please write taxonomy.php file code here. I want to check that code

Comment: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/01/create-custom-taxonomies-wordpress/ cant post all the code